# Export regression results from multiple imputed data

Tags: latex, stata

I am running a fixed effects regression with multiple imputed data:

```
mi est: xtreg zufriedenheit age frau migdir migindir gesund logincnet arbeitslos ///
              verheiratet verwitwet geschieden kinder lognettoverm lognettoschulden ///
              logkonsumschulden, fe i(persnr)
```

This is working fine, but I need to export the estimates into `LaTeX`.

However, I am unsure how to do this since *community-contributed* commands such as `outreg` do not work with multiple imputed data.

Is there any way to export such results?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `post` option of the `mi estimate` prefix as follows:

```
webuse mjsps5, clear
mi xtset school
mi estimate, post: xtreg math5 math3, fe
```

You can then export the results in `LaTeX` using the *community-contributed* 
command `esttab`:

```
esttab ., tex

{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{1}{c}}
\hline\hline
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}\\
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{math5}\\
\hline
math3       &       0.615\sym{***}\\
            &     (17.21)         \\
[1em]
\_cons      &       30.42\sym{***}\\
            &    (169.25)         \\
\hline
\(N\)       &         887         \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
}
```

To install `esttab`, type the following in Stata's command prompt:

```
ssc install estout
```